# Why is my hidden method being overridden by placing the objects in Viewbag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am using VSExpress for Web.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual String Method1()
    {
        return "Base class overridable Method 1";
    }
    public String Method2()
    {
        return "Base class hideable Method 2";
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override String Method1()
    {
        return "Derived class overriden Method 1";
    }
    public new String Method2()
    {
        return "Derived class hidden  Method 2";
    }
}
```

---

When Method 2 is  run in the controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public String Index()
    {

        BaseClass isDefinitelyBase = new BaseClass();
        BaseClass isReallyChild = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass isDefinitelyChild = new DerivedClass();

        return isReallyChild.Method2();
    }
}
```

output is

"Base class hideable Method 2"

---

when the object is placed in a Viewbag and sent to a View, the method is overriden

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        BaseClass isDefinitelyBase = new BaseClass();
        BaseClass isReallyChild = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass isDefinitelyChild = new DerivedClass();

        ViewBag.ReallyChild = isReallyChild;
        return View();
    }
```

### index.cshtml

```
@ViewBag.ReallyChild.Method2();
```

---

the output is:

"Derived class hidden Method 2"

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is that ViewBag is a dynamic variable, and it only knows what the actual type is, it doesn't know that you assigned it from a base type.

So in the view, it only knows that it's the derived type unless you explicitly cast it to the base type, which would give you the base hidden method.  This is not "overridden", by the way.  Overriden means that it's virtual, and that calling the base as the base type gets derived type.  That's not what's happening.. you're calling the instance as the derived type because the dynamic doesn't know any different.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
BaseClass isReallyChild = new DerivedClass();
```

To

```
var isReallyChild = new DerivedClass();
```

`ViewBag` sets the type at runtime versus at compilation. The reason you get the base class method is because the type is still the base class.

To get the base from the ViewBag, try:

```
var base = (BaseClass)ViewBag.ReallyChild;
var res = base.Method2();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand him.. he's not trying to get "derived" in the first instance, he's trying to get "base" in the dynamic.

Comment: Thnx, I'll add to this answer